# Bootstrap affix breaks element width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I made a basic sidebar with menu and an area with content. Split them by 3 and 9 columns respectively. And it looks fine until i apply `.affix` class to sidebar to make it sticky. Now sidebar gets width of parent to calculate self width from somewere else, but not from `.row` or `.container`, and gets bigger than it must.

What should i do to make sidebar 25% width again and be sticky at same time? Why it gets bigger? Thanks!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03wx0f7r/17/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 left affix">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 right">
      Some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `.affix` class is part of a JavaScript plugin. Applying the css class directly does not provide the full functionality of the plugin. This doesn't directly answer your question, but I hope it helps. You can check out the documentation here:     https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#affix

Comment: It's pointed by this link, that i _must_ provide css for positioning and width. Not explained why, but thank you anyway, @JeremyE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare a width for affixed element.

```
.left {
  border: 2px solid green;
 width:15% !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i can set width less than 25%, and `.left` will not overlap `.right`. Fine. But why 25% doesn't work?

Comment: Because when the element in fixed position is positioned relative to the viewport. So the 25% is from the body's width.